# Selenium Scraping API data

Tags: api, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm new to scraping and have a question if I technically can do what I would like to do.

I would like to scrape a website but I see that there is actual more information in the API behind the website that there is on the website itself.
As i can see the data of the API in my webbrowser is there a way to scrape this data like **scraping** the front-end with selenium for example or not?

In the image you can see some of the API data of the site.

Thanks a lot!

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7eCq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of work to parse that object, but it can be done. In order to intercept those network calls, you can use the [selenium-wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) library

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"E:\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.delhaize.be/nl-be/shop/Verse-groenten-en-fruit/c/v2FRU?q=:relevance&sort=relevance')

#accept that privacy to enable the analitics
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@data-testid,'cookie-popup-accept')]").click()

# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        if request.url == 'https://api.delhaize.be/':
            print(
                request.url,
                request.body,
                request.response.status_code,
                request.response.headers['Content-Type']
            )
```

The response will be something like, that will require parsing:

```
https://api.delhaize.be/ b'{"operationName":"GetCategoryProductSearch","variables":{"lang":"nl","searchQuery":":relevance","sort":"relevance","category":"v2FRU","pageNumber":0,"pageSize":20,"filterFlag":true},"query":"query GetCategoryProductSearch($anonymousCartCookie: String, $lang: String, $searchQuery: String, $pageSize: Int, $pageNumber: Int, $category: String, $sort: String, $filterFlag: Boolean) {\\n  categoryProductSearch(anonymousCartCookie: $anonymousCartCookie, lang: $lang, searchQuery: $searchQuery, pageSize: $pageSize, pageNumber: $pageNumber, category: $category, sort: $sort, filterFlag: $filterFlag) {\\n    products {\\n      ...ProductBlockDetails\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    breadcrumbs {\\n      ...Breadcrumbs\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    facets {\\n      ...Facets\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    sorts {\\n      name\\n      selected\\n      code\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    pagination {\\n      ...Pagination\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    currentQuery {\\n      query {\\n        value\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    categorySearchTree {\\n      categoryDataList {\\n        categoryCode\\n        categoryData {\\n          facetData {\\n            count\\n            name\\n            query {\\n              query {\\n                value\\n                __typename\\n              }\\n              url\\n              __typename\\n            }\\n            selected\\n            __typename\\n          }\\n          subCategories\\n          __typename\\n        }\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      level\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment ProductBlockDetails on Product {\\n  available\\n  averageRating\\n  numberOfReviews\\n  manufacturerName\\n  manufacturerSubBrandName\\n  code\\n  freshnessDuration\\n  freshnessDurationTipFormatted\\n  frozen\\n  recyclable\\n  images {\\n    format\\n    imageType\\n    url\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  maxOrderQuantity\\n  limitedAssortment\\n  name\\n  onlineExclusive\\n  potentialPromotions {\\n    alternativePromotionMessage\\n    code\\n    priceToBurn\\n    promotionType\\n    range\\n    redemptionLevel\\n    toDisplay\\n    description\\n    title\\n    promoBooster\\n    simplePromotionMessage\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  price {\\n    approximatePriceSymbol\\n    currencySymbol\\n    formattedValue\\n    priceType\\n    supplementaryPriceLabel1\\n    supplementaryPriceLabel2\\n    showStrikethroughPrice\\n    discountedPriceFormatted\\n    unit\\n    unitCode\\n    unitPrice\\n    value\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  purchasable\\n  productProposedPackaging\\n  productProposedPackaging2\\n  stock {\\n    inStock\\n    inStockBeforeMaxAdvanceOrderingDate\\n    partiallyInStock\\n    availableFromDate\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  url\\n  previouslyBought\\n  nutriScoreLetter\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment Breadcrumbs on SearchBreadcrumb {\\n  facetCode\\n  facetName\\n  facetValueName\\n  facetValueCode\\n  removeQuery {\\n    query {\\n      value\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment Facets on Facet {\\n  code\\n  name\\n  category\\n  facetUiType\\n  values {\\n    code\\n    count\\n    name\\n    query {\\n      query {\\n        value\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    selected\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment Pagination on Pagination {\\n  currentPage\\n  totalResults\\n  totalPages\\n  sort\\n  __typename\\n}\\n"}' 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```